# Selection of values in a df using steps and location

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Well this is the context, given this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(100, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
```

I want to select the values of A given a fixed interval. I wrote this script:

```
n=0
for i in range(0, len(df), 22):
    if i+22+n < len(df):
        print(df.A.iloc[[i+n, i+22+n]])
    else: print(i+n, len(df)-1)
    n+=1
```

The result that I want:

```
0     0.373158
22    0.173096
Name: A, dtype: float64
23    0.590712
45    0.446213
Name: A, dtype: float64
46    0.567147
68    0.577576
Name: A, dtype: float64
69    0.823834
91    0.891792
Name: A, dtype: float64
92 99
```

And it works, but I think there is a better solution by using pandas or numpy, what do you think?

Best regards!

A better solution of the problem

Comment: What is the range of values you want to select? If some fixed rows from i1 to i2, then df.iloc should do the work. For instance, rows from 2 to 4: `dfs = df.iloc[2:5]`.

Comment: Hi @msi_gerva, the range values I want to select is determined by an interval.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = 22
hist = int(df.index[-1] / a)
b = (a + 1) * (hist - 1)
aaa = np.linspace((0, a), (b, b + a), hist).astype(int)


if aaa[-1, 1] < df.index[-1]:#If the residual range is not needed.
    aaa = np.vstack([aaa, [b + a + 1, df.index[-1]]])#Comment out these two lines.


for i in aaa:
    print(df.A.iloc[[i[0], i[1]]])
```

Here, a two-dimensional list is created to select the desired rows.

Or (which is much faster), turn the aaa list into a one-dimensional list and get all the necessary rows at once:

```
print(df.iloc[aaa.ravel()])
```

Output

```
           A         B         C
0   0.008490  0.353145  0.644969
22  0.662565  0.928465  0.741433
23  0.582470  0.880653  0.748420
45  0.311704  0.361590  0.690090
46  0.352363  0.548714  0.528238
68  0.661500  0.934672  0.683982
69  0.981060  0.900127  0.442461
91  0.713984  0.628793  0.703409
92  0.716954  0.837737  0.688939
99  0.096911  0.922000  0.552415
```

Comment: Amazing! Love the solution thanks @inquirer

Comment: @ControlSolution you can vote if you like it.